# Variable changes after reloading the page

Tags: php

So I am having a problem. I (probably) know what the problem is, but I dont know how to fix it.

I have a forum, with questions and comments. Now the username of the person who posted the question/ comment is a link to his/her profile. When I get to that link, I check wether the persons username is my username. If it is I can edit the profile with a button. Now when I click the button, I get errors and I'll explain why I think so. First i'll show you my code. This is on top of my profile page:

```
if(!empty($_GET['thread_username'])){
    //If thread username link was clicked
    $profileusername = $_GET['thread_username'];
}
else if(!empty($_GET['comment_username'])){
    //If comment username was clicked
    $profileusername = $_GET['comment_username'];
}
else{
}
$profileusername=$mysqli2->real_escape_string($profileusername);
```

The button on the profilepage reloads the page(and more) so that it goes through this code again, **BUT** the `$_GET['thread_username']`and the  `$_GET['comment_username']` are from the previous page. So when I reload it, these doesn't exist(So they are empty) and the page goes through the else. I have tested if it goes through the else by just giving the $profileusername a variable and it does. So when it goes through the else, the `$profileusername` isn't declared so I get all sort of errors. My problem is that when the page reloads, it shouldn't go through the else. It should just check the $_GET, but the page says it doesn't exist which I understand but how can I fix this?

My form now:

```
    echo
<<<EOT
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<input name="edit" type="submit" value="edit"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="thread_username" value="{$_REQUEST["thread_username"]}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="comment_username" value="{$_REQUEST["comment_username"]}" />
</form>
EOT;
```

Comment: Do you reload the exact same URI? If yes, $_GET should still be filled with the same values. Or do you submit a form via POST? The $_GET isn't probably set any more and you'd have to switch to $_POST

Comment: Rather than using `!empty($variable)`, use `isset($variable)`

Comment: @Reeno i submit via POST. What do you mean with:"The $_GET isn't probably set any more and you'd have to switch to $_POST" How can I just switch to $_POST all of the sudden?

Comment: If you're posting a value to a PHP page, you use $_POST to retrieve it.  $_GET is specifically for getting the values from the URI query string.  $_REQUEST can be used for both.

Comment: @Coulton But I can't just replace the $_GET with $_POST. It gives me errors

Comment: If you POST a form, the $_GET variables get lost. Add the thread_username/comment_username to your form (`'<input type="hidden" name="thread_username" value="'.$_REQUEST['thread_username'].'" />'`) and refer to $_REQUEST['thread_username'] instead of $_GET

Comment: @Reeno syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING  at the 

'<input type="hidden" name="thread_username" value="'.$_REQUEST['thread_username'].'" />'

Comment: I don't how how you use quotes in the rest of your script... Think a little and don't just copy my code :)

Comment: @Reeno <input type="hidden" name="thread_username" value="'{$_REQUEST['thread_username']}'"/> Ok I got this now. But still get the same error as in the beginning.

Comment: Please add your new code to your question (the if clause and relevant parts of the form you're posting)

Comment: @Reeno I got it to work. Youre solution did work! thanks. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @loko Glad I could help! I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET, see the comments to the question.

Comment: The only annoying thing now is, when I click on the thread_username on the previous page, It shows me Undefined Index comment_username
And  when I click on the comment_username , It shows me Undefined Index thread_username

Comment: Add the `<input type="hidden" ...>` only if the variable is set: `if(isset($_REQUEST["thread_username"])) { echo '<input type="hidden" name="thread_username" value="'.$_REQUEST['thread_username'].'" />' }` (and the same for the `comment_username`)